# Responsive menu with clickable sub-menu that changes place depending screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

My best describing the situation:

The menu on mobile is vertical and on desktop is horizontal.

```css
.menu {
        list-style-type: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: column;
        @media (min-width: 768px) {
        flex-direction: row;        
        justify-content: space-between;
      };    
    }
```

The first menu link is a clickable sub-menu. This complicates the situation because it means sub-menu needs to be duplicated so that on mobile(when the menu is vertical) sub-menu is in-between menu links and on desktop(when a menu is horizontal) below the menu links (so sub-menu does not break the alignment of `justify-content: space-between;`).
HTML:

```html
<footer>
  <hr />
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle" href="#submenu">submenu</a>
      <ol id="submenu" class="table-of-contents toggle-content is-mobile">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="content-entry">sub-menu</a>
        </li>
        ...
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ol id="submenu" class="table-of-contents toggle-content is-desktop">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="content-entry">lorem the ipsum placeholder text</a>
    </li>
    ...
  </ol>
  <hr />
  <p class="additional">some text</p>
</footer>
```

So far the sub-menu appears as described above, but the problem arises in making sub-menu clickable, because sub-menu has the same ID. The question is how to make sub-menu is my scenario clickable in both mobile and desktop.

Please look at jsfiddle example (changing width of result window)
https://jsfiddle.net/virsis12/c4Lt2krm/31/

Comment: I am so sorry for editing when question published. Now the fiddle and question is updated.

Comment: You have a couple of design elements that are making your life difficult. First, the duplicate IDs - that is never okay. Why can't you use classes there? _(Classes/IDs ARE virtually identical in function, except that IDs must always be unique... Is there something you can't wrap your head around? Please tell us.)_ Next, in your demo you are using identical placeholder text for the two OL sections. Change the placeholder text for the first group from `lorem the ipsum etc` to just `lorem` and re-run the demo. Resize the screen and I think you'll discover something you missed before.

Comment: @cssyphus double IDs because am very novice with Javascript. As of the placeholder text, i understand what you mean, that is why the submenu with its content on desktop goes below the menu, so there is no place. My demo does not work as it should.
So far the only solution is to place the submenu as last link in menu, then I dont need to dublicate submenu, but I hope there is a way to trigger submenu, perhaps using two unique IDs, just, like I said, am bad with javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to dublicate the html for `#submenu`.

You should move the `#submenu` inside the first `li` element and on desktop screens, set its `position` to `absolute`. Use javascript to show or hide the sub-menu.

```js
const toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');

toggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  submenu.classList.toggle('showSubMenu');
});
```

```css
ol, ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.submenu-container {
  position: relative;
}

.table-of-contents {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.table-of-contents li {
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.showSubMenu {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .table-of-contents {
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    top: 120%;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .menu {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer class=" footer">
  <hr>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="submenu-container">
      <a class="toggle" href="#submenu">submenu</a>
      <ol id="submenu" class="table-of-contents">
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="content-entry">placeholder text</a></li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
  </ul>
  <hr>
  <p class="additional">some text</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing solution. This is good example that designers need to think in terms of what is possible with the technology.